What is the process to fetch access token from refresh token and save it into the cookies in next js 14?
I'm using next js 14 application for frontend. A signin form is created. When a user logged in, it hits the app/actions/auth.ts server action file. There I set a cookies named session with accessToken and refreshToken and it's visible to the browser cookies. Now if api is responding with error message 'Token expired', I want to fetch new accessToken with that refreshToken and update the cookies with newly fetched accessToken & refreshToken.
I'm using app/api/getRefreshToken/route.ts file to fetch new token. Here I can't access my cookies which are created in server action file app/actions/auth.ts. Another thing if I set cookies in that api route handler, it's also not accessible to my page component.
How can I do that?
